# MacBook USB Hub with mini displayports

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, displayport

I have the new 2015 MacBook. I am trying to find a HUB (or Docking Station) can can allow me to hook up two 4K Displays while supplying power to the MacBook.

I don't care if it uses HDMI or mini Display but my searches on the Internet tend to show mini Display is the way to go for 4K display.

I was a backer for **HUB+**. The HUB+ has been cancelled in their latest update.

But there are other projects available like HydraDock, Pluggable and OWC USB-C

Aside from Plugable's Unfunded Kickstarter Campaign, I don't see any solution to have 2 4K displays at the same time.

---

From Pluggable's web site

> The Plugable Ultimate Dock utilizes two unique yet complimentary
>   technologies:
>
> USB 3.1 Type-C supports a feature called “VESA Alternate Mode” which
>   works with the built-in graphics processor on supported systems to
>   provide video output at resolutions up to 4K. The other two display
>   outputs in the Ultimate Dock are enabled by the DisplayLink DL-3900
>   graphics processor, which can support two additional 1080P displays at
>   60Hz.

Their Kickstarter failed so I am not sure if they will ever manufacture this item. I assumed OWC is doing the same thing or something similar to drive the displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB doesn't have direct access to a GPU. Driving two 4K displays would be quite difficult, if at all possible. In all honesty, if you wanted to drive two 4K displays, the new MacBook was NOT the computer you should have purchased. It can barely handle its own display.

Comment: How about 1 4K display

Comment: Still not likely. The new MacBook's GPU is low-end. Its built-in display is very high-resolution. This poor combination results in a laptop which is only JUST able to handle its own resolution. People have reported performance issues with the built-in display (which isn't even 4k by itself). I don't honestly see how you could usably hook up a 4K display to this thing.

Comment: I updated the question to include text from their website

Comment: Fair enough, but that isn't USB-mode. The GPU is the real culprit here. USB-C is, admittedly, capable of supporting two 4K displays via alternate modes (the Thunderbolt mode is capable too), but the GPU just can't do it. A MacBook Pro could, a MacBook Air reportedly could, but with (if I recall) some performance issues due to a stronger GPU, and a lower-res built-in display. The new MacBook just can't do it.

Comment: I'm so disappointed. I really just need it for Xcode development. (No 4K Video Editing). Why 4K? well I would like to see more code on screen at once (maybe open documentation side by side). I suppose the 2nd Gen MacBook maybe the one I need.